# What packages/functions are imported by default in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In Java the `java.lang` package is imported by default.
In kotlin a number of functions and classes are available without being imported, like `println` and kotlins `Array`, `Int`, etc types.
What else is imported by default and where is it defined?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Kotlin stdlib has `kotlin` root package and its subpackages [(see the full list with the content)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/).

It seems not to be documented anywhere which of them are imported by default, but a [peek into Kotlin Github sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/321a19a247ec09bfc351a0bda768313735781a49/compiler/frontend.java/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/jvm/platform/JvmPlatform.kt) suggests that these packages are imported for JVM target platform:

- `java.lang.*`
- `kotlin.*`
- `kotlin.annotation.*`
- `kotlin.jvm.*`
- `kotlin.collections.*`
- `kotlin.ranges.*`
- `kotlin.sequences.*`
- `kotlin.text.*`
- `kotlin.io.*`
- `kotlin.coroutines.*` *(to be added in Kotlin 1.1, not present in 1.0.4)*

I've manually tested them, and the list above is true for Kotlin 1.0.4. And these stdlib packages are **not** imported by default:

- `kotlin.comparisons.*`
- `kotlin.concurrent.*`
- `kotlin.properties.*`
- `kotlin.reflect.*`
- `kotlin.reflect.jvm.*`
- `kotlin.system.*`

As [@Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1544715/magnus) noted, the default imports for JS platform [are different](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/383b7f89a6101fd9b2db417f52e3df27781718c5/js/js.frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/resolve/JsPlatform.kt).

Comment: Found a relevant Kotlin source -- updated the answer.

Comment: Worth noting that the JS platform also has slightly different imports https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/383b7f89a6101fd9b2db417f52e3df27781718c5/js/js.frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/js/resolve/JsPlatform.kt

Answer (score 8):

The official documentation for the list of Kotlin's default imports (which is likely to be change with new versions of the language) is here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html#default-imports

As of 2018-02-11 it includes the following:

> - kotlin.*
> - kotlin.annotation.*
> - kotlin.collections.*
> - kotlin.comparisons.* (since 1.1)
> - kotlin.io.*
> - kotlin.ranges.*
> - kotlin.sequences.*
> - kotlin.text.*
>
> Additional packages are imported depending on the target platform:
>
> JVM:
>
> - java.lang.*
> - kotlin.jvm.*
>
> JS:
>
> - kotlin.js.*

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18785659)

Comment: Changed the answer to include both.