# Is it possible to instruct Kotlin compiler to import additional packages by default (as it does with its own packages)?

Tags: kotlin

I have a bunch of classes in `my.framework` package which I want to use everywhere in my project without importing them explicitly (without using `import my.framework.*` statement). Can I instruct Kotlin compiler somehow so it includes additional packages to the list of the ones imported by default (as it does with `kotlin.collections`, `kotlin.text`, and so on)?

Comment: how do you compile?

Comment: But does it matter? Command-line tools/Maven/Gradle/within IDE...

Comment: I've some experiences with command line

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find an easy way to do it, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40076096/8106427) answer, there is a [specific file](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/321a19a247ec09bfc351a0bda768313735781a49/compiler/frontend.java/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/jvm/platform/JvmPlatform.kt) in the Kotlin compiler, you could change to modify the default imports. 
You will have to:
1. Clone the [kotlin repository](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin):
`git clone https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin`
2. Modify the specific file, to import some additional packages by default.
For example to import `kotlin.reflect` by default you modify the kotlin file located in compiler/frontend.java/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/resolve/jvm/platform/JvmPlatform.kt relative from the project root like that:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2010-2015 JetBrains s.r.o.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.platform

import org.jetbrains.kotlin.builtins.DefaultBuiltIns
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.DescriptorUtils
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.ImportPath
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.PlatformConfigurator
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.TargetPlatform
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.DescriptorKindFilter
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.MemberScope
import java.util.*

object JvmPlatform : TargetPlatform("JVM") {
    override val defaultImports: List<ImportPath> = ArrayList<ImportPath>().apply {
        add(ImportPath("java.lang.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.annotation.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.jvm.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.collections.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.coroutines.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.ranges.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.sequences.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.text.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.io.*"))
        add(ImportPath("kotlin.reflect.*")) //This is the important change!!! 
        fun addAllClassifiersFromScope(scope: MemberScope) {
            for (descriptor in scope.getContributedDescriptors(DescriptorKindFilter.CLASSIFIERS, MemberScope.ALL_NAME_FILTER)) {
                add(ImportPath(DescriptorUtils.getFqNameSafe(descriptor), false))
            }
        }

        val builtIns = DefaultBuiltIns.Instance
        for (builtinPackageFragment in builtIns.builtInsPackageFragments) {
            addAllClassifiersFromScope(builtinPackageFragment.getMemberScope())
        }
    }

    override val platformConfigurator: PlatformConfigurator = JvmPlatformConfigurator
}
```

3. Recompile the kotlin compiler:
   `gradle dist`
4. Use it and see if it works:
   The kotlin compiler jar is located in `dist/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar` and to run the compiler you use `dist/kotlinc/bin/kotlinc`.

Maybe it's easier to just import the needed packages instead of manually recompiling the kotlin compiler (;